# Add New line in existing extent report

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a scenario where I need to add a new line to an existing extent report, how can I achieve this.

[image]

I need to new line in TC3, the remaining all should be displayed as how they are displaying now.

Answer (score 0):

to add a new line. it depends on what your adding, considering its a failed case.

to add a Marker with String of Test Case Fail

```
 test.get().fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+ "Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
```

or simply log the failed case.

```
test.get().log(Status.FAIL, "Test Failed");
```